# Check condition inside group in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by, having

I have a table with information related to students belonging to courses, that take exams with certain levels (knowdledge_level). For each knowledge level, there are several exams (in case of knowledge_level 1, exams are those with ID 1 and 2, and in case of knowledge_level 2, exams are those with ID 3 and 4).

```
Course     Student   Exam_ID       Knowdledge_level    Passed
A          25        1             1                   yes
A          25        2             1                   yes
A          25        3             2                   no
A          25        4             2                   yes
A          26        1             1                   no
A          26        2             1                   no
A          26        3             2                   no
A          26        4             2                   no
```

What I'd like to obtain  for each student (25 and 26), is the highest level of knowledge for which all exams have been passed. In case of student 25, the result should be 1, because he has passed all the exams of level 1 but failed one exam of level 2, so he could not achieve knowledge level 2 completely, and in case of student 26 the level should be NULL (or zero) because he hasn't passed any exam.

I'd like to know which query should return the desired result, in this case:

```
Course     Student   Knowdledge_level    
A          25        1  
A          26        NULL (or zero)
```

Could you help me? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the boolean aggregate function [`bool_and()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select course, student, max(knowledge_level) as knowledge_level
from (
    select 
        course, 
        student, 
        case when bool_and(passed) then knowledge_level else 0 end as knowledge_level
    from exams
    group by course, student, knowledge_level
    ) s
group by course, student
order by course, student

 course | student | knowledge_level 
--------+---------+-----------------
 A      |      25 |               1
 A      |      26 |               0
(2 rows)
```

In [this live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=816df5a5ffbc0a4e607d388c4b8b62d0) you can see how to build the query in simple steps.